# Filenesting not working for Class or Shared Library Projects

Tags: visual-studio-2019, solution-explorer

In Visual Studio 2019 Web Projects, file nesting in the Solution Explorer works like a charm. If you add a file named `ClassA.cs` and another file named `ClassA.Custom.cs` they get nested as it should be.

[image]

But for Class or Shared Library Projects it doesn't work at all. It doesn't matter if you change the settings to "Default" or  "Web" or even add a custom File Nesting Setting.

[image]

Is there a way, to configure Visual Studio 2019 so that file nesting also works in Class Library Projects and alike?

I know one could change the *.csproj files manually to add Entries with the `<DependentUpon>` Tag like it was in earlier Visual Studio versions, but i really don't like the idea of changing this manually for all the classes i have.

```
<Compile Update="$(ProjectDir)\Person.*.cs">
  <DependentUpon>$(ProjectDir)\Person.cs</DependentUpon>
</Compile>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Original Answer:**

There is an issue about this topic active on Github.com and Developer Community:

- [Issue 5722](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/5722)
- [Developer Community 483587](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/file-nesting-not-working-for-all-class-or-shared-l/483587)

A workaround for this problem exists - at least working for .Net Standard 2.0. Add the following lines to your *.csproj file:

`<ItemGroup> <ProjectCapability Include="DynamicDependentFile" /> <ProjectCapability Include="DynamicFileNesting" /> </ItemGroup>`

**Update:**

This issue should be fixed from Visual Studio 2019 Verison 16.7 onwards.

Comment: This did not work for me in a .NET Core 3.1 Class Library project which contains TypeScript source files and output JS. I'm using VS 2019 16.10.

Comment: this ***does*** actually work with .NET Core 3.1 libraries... but there must be a **.filenesting.json** added at the solution level. It seems that it's also required that it lives inside a "*Solution Items*" folder. Desired nesting settings can be optionally defined stand-alone.. instead of creating a new file with ALL existing default settings, as long as you set `"root": false` - essentially appending settings onto the existing default configuration.

Comment: This seems to be broken in VS2022 :(

Answer (score 12):

For the people using Visual Studio 2022 and non-web projects, this is the solution from [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/project-system/issues/5722#issuecomment-1048692608) that helped me to fix it.

> To enable configurable file nesting for non-web projects in VS 2022, add this to your .csproj file:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectCapability Include="ConfigurableFileNesting" />
  <ProjectCapability Include="ConfigurableFileNestingFeatureEnabled" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 4):

Piggy Backing onto @phihi's answer.

@phihi's solution ***does*** actually work with .NET Core 3.1 libraries; but in addition, there must be a **.filenesting.json** file added at the **solution** level. It seems that it's also required that the new **.filenesting.json** lives inside a "*Solution Items*" folder (folder name may not matter) at the solution level.

[image]

Desired nesting settings can be optionally defined stand-alone.. instead of creating a new file with ALL existing default settings, as long as you set "root": false - this essentially appends settings onto the existing default configuration without losing any default settings.

[image]

Great success

[image]

Comment: Working for .NET 5.0 as well.  Very nice!

Comment: @Mat thanks for verifying!

Comment: This does not work with `Class Library` with .NET 5.0. (Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 Version 16.11.0)

Comment: Not working for me either in VS Community 2022 RC3. My file is stored next to the solution with a solution item added and the contents set to the same thing as the screenshot, except in my case it's `.Records.cs`.

Comment: @NathanAldenSr you mentioned that your filenesting.json file is stored next to the solution; whereas is should be within the solution, but outside of any projects… is that what you mean? And Still not working? I have not verified this in VS 2022.

Comment: It's stored as a sibling file to the solution file, yes. It's also a solution item. FWIW, I am pretty sure Microsoft disabled this feature for all but ASP.NET Core projects due to performance concerns.

Comment: @NathanAldenSr can confirm: a non-ASP.NET Core solution I have that nests files with VS2019 does **not** nest them in VS2022.

Comment: Update: The 17.1 preview has "Configurable File Nesting" listed as a "Preview Feature".

Comment: I know it's an old question but can I nest file from a different folder?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue with the Class Library project on .net6. Instead of using the *Class Library* template use *Razor Class Library*.

[Template window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/596fd.png)

You want the *Razor Component option* to be in place in the *Add new item* window.

[Available item templates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7xIT.png)

Answer (score 0):

if you open a file in the solution rather than the solution itself, the aspx, aspx.vb disappears. Just by opening the solution, rather than a file, the nesting was solved in my case

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).