# How to apply nested files in Visual Studio 2019 for Class Library project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019.
Version 16.9.5.

I want *.Generated.cs files to be nested under corresponding *.cs file in a Class Library project exactly like in does in a RestApi Console Application project.

File nesting is enabled for both projects, Active Settings is set to 'Web' for both.

[image: Class Library]

[image: RestApi Console Library]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Visual Studio 2019 (16.10.3) here. Based on the recommendation of [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59406202/2567232) I got it to work by putting the following in the .csproj file, then reopening the solution. I don't know if it matters or not, but I put this as the last elements group the closing `</Project>` tag in the file.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectCapability Include="DynamicDependentFile" />
  <ProjectCapability Include="DynamicFileNesting" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. It works like a charm ! Thank you !